# Replace null with '' in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to Replace null with '' in Pandas:

```
final_data.replace("null","")
```

With this in dataframe, null replaces with NaN. With `final_data.fillna(" ")` NaN not replaces with ''. Any help would be appreciated.

```
no             ip
20457          NaN
20458          NaN
20459          NaN
20460          NaN
20461          127.0.0.1
20462          NaN
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: @jezrael I have edited my question

Comment: Hmmm, `final_data = final_data.fillna("")` for me working.

Comment: Or even `final_data.fillna("", inplace=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final_data = final_data.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('', np.nan)
```

Comment: This is excessive.  The solution in jezrael's comment should do it.

Comment: @Peter Jezrael's comment is correct but this one works for me. I don't know why